# How to get the specific property value from .properties file in Spring Data Repository interface method @Query

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am able to get the property value in Spring classes like below:

```
@Value("${database.name}")
private String databaseName;
```

I have to execute a native query by joining different tables which are in different databases.

```
@Query(value="select t1.* FROM db1.table1 t1 INNER JOIN db2.table2 t2 ON t2.t1_id1 = t1.id1")
```

Instead of hard coding database names i.e., db1 and db2 here, I have to get them from properties file.

how to get the property value inside the @Query annotation in Spring Data JPA Repository ?

Comment: A good question here is what you mean by 2 diff databases? Because if you're talking about two absolutely different DB servers you probably need to configure 2 data sources, or you can talk about 2 different schemas and that's another case.

Comment: But in both cases, I'd say, your repository should not be aware about database name. You better reconsider your design, but if you cannot change it - I assume you will have to hardcode DB names in @Query.

Comment: two different schemas at the moment. I have configured using: https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

Comment: Have you consider creating a Service, inject entityManager there and create your query using entityManager or criteria API, you can build more flexible queries using them. And you can inject values from `.properties` to this service and use then when building queries with EntityManager

Comment: Instead of using repositories, for this specific case, you could create a query with EntityManager instead (injecting it to some Component where you can also inject `properties`)

Comment: I have tried using EntityManager and Native Query but I have to create ResultSetMapping to get "table1" entity. Otherwise ResultSet not able to map to that entity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible, but if not, you can consider this approach:

Instead of using properties in Repository's `@Query` directly, you can use params in the query but when you call the actual method - you can provide values from `.properties`.

Imagine you have simple repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  // query with param
  @Query("select u from User u where u.lastname = :lastname")
  User findByLastname(@Param("lastname") String lastname);

}
```

Then, let's say you have some `Service` or `Controller` where you need to use your `Repository` - you can inject properties there and pass them to your method:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    // this comes from .properties
    @Value("${user.lastName}")
    private String userLastName;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public User getUser() {
        // you pass it as param to the repo method which
        // injects it into query
        return userRepository.findByLastname(userLastName);
    }
}
```

This is just an example. But I believe it may be useful.

Happy hacking :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. yes, we can send the value to repository method and can use it in @Query. It will work for one place only. If I want to use the database name for different join tables in one native query. I don't think its correct approach.

Comment: Maybe be you could add more specific details about your case? So far, from what I understood you're trying to do - I would say your design is not good. Adding a database name to a query sounds like something wrong for me.

Comment: It is not wrong, actually it makes sense when you're doing cross schema joins. I'm having the same issue, although I was able to pass the value, because it has a "." after it, it does not find the param field, as it is treating it as if I was trying to access a field inside my Param, as in paramName.fieldIntheParam, when I was trying to use the string as the table name dot the column in the table. also I had to make the schema name configurable, another level but the same problem. This is a very tricky problem to work around.