# How to reference a property value inside a query?

Tags: java, jpql

There is a repository :

```
@Repository
public interface ArticleDao extends CrudRepository<Article, Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT ITMREF_0,ACCCOD_0 FROM  [tomx3v6].[TOMCTB].[ITMMASTER] where YITMOXA_0 = :itmoxa ")
    public Article getByCode(@Param("itmoxa") String code);

}
```

I want to make the `TOMCTB` to be not constant like in the above snippet but to be dynamic gotten from a properties file. How to achieve that ?

Comment: Doesn't `nativeQuery = true` mean, that it's sql?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53171308/how-to-get-the-specific-property-value-from-properties-file-in-spring-data-repo

Comment: @Andronicus yes it is sql but the context is JPQL !

Comment: Ok, thanks for the lesson:)